# Find error with this simple code?

Tags: c, scanf

I have been stuck on these lines for like a hour. Can someone help me checking with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 20;
int main(void)
{
  int fckingshit[NUM],i;
  printf("Enter 20 integers now: ");
  for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    scanf("%d",&fckingshit[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

I got Error messages below.

```
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:5: error: expected ']' before ';' token
test.c:7: error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:7: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:7: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:7: error: expected expression before ';' token
test.c:8: error: 'fckingshit' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: remove the ; in the #define

Comment: Please use meaningful names for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

`#define NUM 20;` is wrong. It should be

```
#define NUM 20
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `;` in the macro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 20
int main(void)
{
  int fckingshit[NUM];
  int i;
  printf("Enter 20 integers now: ");
  for(i=0;i<NUM;i++)
    scanf("%d",&fckingshit[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Working Example: http://ideone.com/0xawxJ

Answer (score 1):

`#define`'s don't need a semicolon after the definition as they are not instructions per say. Instead the pre-processor replaces the body of the `#define` every time it encounters a usage of it within the code. In your case after the code is pre-processed, it expands the `#define` to `int fckingshit[20;],i;`, thus the compiler generates an error.

Same with the `for` statement, it get's translated to `for(i=0;i<20;;i++)`, which obviously is incorrect (too many semicolons :)

Comment: "*Instead the compiler replaces...*" No. The preprocessor does. Not the compiler

Comment: Right, thanks for the note, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As all the answers say, the error is the semicolon in the macro definition.

```
#define NUM 20;
```

Should be:

```
#define NUM 20
```

The `#define` directives are part of a set of directives called [Preprocessor Directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Other examples of this directives are `#include` and `#ifdef` among others. These directives are interpreted by the preprocessor before the compiler transform the source code to a binary file. The `#define` acts like a super powerful "find and replaces", so when the preprocessor process your example it ends looking like this:

```
#define NUM 20;
...
  int fckingshit[20;];
...
```

In fact, the preprocessor generate something like the following for you example:

```
...
# 493 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
# 2 "test.c" 2

int main(void)
{
  int fckingshit[20;],i;
  printf("Enter 20 integers now: ");
  for(i=0;i<20;;i++)
    scanf("%d",&fckingshit[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

It's much longer but i trim the first 200 lines. As you see your `#define NUM 20;` disappear and your array declaration is now `fckingshit[20;]` that cause the issue. Also the preprocessor expands the `#include <stdio.h>` to the full path of the file (and the other 200 lines i trim). You can try it out with the command: `gcc -E [name of your .c file]`

*An advice: don't project your anger to your code. I sometimes find my self hating the code i'm writing but name things like `void i_hate_you(int die, char idiot){...` don't help you solve the problem. In fact it's the opposite.*

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

remove; after #define NUM 20;
it should be #define NUM 20

Answer (score -1):

`#define` is used without ";", that should fix your problem

Comment: `void main(void)` is wrong. And remove number 3)

Comment: May you explain to me why void main is wrong?
And I just went right into the problem with the Linker Error, I thought I could help him save some minutes of trying

Comment: `void main(void)` is wrong because newer versions of C won't support it. Also, as per the C11 standard, the signature of `main` should be either `int main()` or `int main(void)`. And as for 3), how do you know that the OP uses Visual Studio? There are other errors too like not checking the return value of `scanf` etc. But they are not very important here. I don't see any reason why you should assume that the OP uses VS2012 and that he/she has faced that error.

Comment: ok, i will edit my answer.
Always worked with void main(void) (C, C++, C#) and it was fine.